# Can't get a GPS fix on an Acer Liquid Gallant Duo

Tags: gps, smartphone, android-gps

*It's already a long story... I bought my phone sometime in 2013, and found that it's GPS doesn't work, just after the warranty expired. I tired everything to get it function properly without any success, and finally gave up. Up until now I could live without it, but right now I'm really in need of this functionality, and only because of that I'd have to buy a new smartphone now if it can't be fixed.*

---

Here's the issue: I turn on GPS positioning in the OS, and open up some GPS tester application, and this is what happens: After a couple of seconds, it finds the first satellite, and in 1-2 minutes I already have 6-7 or even 8 of them. - So it seems the hardware is OK, the receiver works. But after that, I cannot get a GPS fix. I can wait 10-20-30 minutes, or even waited for an hour...Nothing happens. No position fix, GPS useless. I've tried 10+ GPS apps, the result is always the same. They see the satellites, but never establish a position fix.

What I've done so far: I read on xda-developers that this phone for some reason doesn't have a gps.conf file in system/etc which could cause the problem, so I downloaded one for my country, rooted my phone and pasted it to that folder. Nothing changed. I'm out of ideas, and there's nothing more I could find on the internet. Any ideas here? Or should I get a new phone? It's really annoying because it seems it's not a hardware issue, so it should be able to be fixed somehow...

Btw that's the content of my gps.conf file in system/etc for Austria, the country I live in:

```
NTP_SERVER=at.pool.ntp.org
XTRA_SERVER_1=http://xtra1.gpsonextra.net/
xtra.bin
XTRA_SERVER_2=http://xtra2.gpsonextra.net/
xtra.bin
XTRA_SERVER_3=http://xtra3.gpsonextra.net/
xtra.bin
SUPL_HOST=supl.google.com
SUPL_PORT=7276
```

(I have no idea what it's for.)

Answer (score 1):

Unassisted GPS in a GPS module which has never been turned on, or has to find a new position solution, can actually 2-4 hours at worse. Adding to this, a single processor Android smart phone such as yours likely throttles severely, and is not likely to schedule much resource for non-essential routines.

Be sure to turn on 'Google Location Services' to enable assisted GPS for a faster position solution. If any factory setting has a toggle for location- assistance, make sure it is enabled. Be sure to move away from buildings so the sensors view of the sky is widest.